# Why do I keep getting redirected to "/cgi-bin/redirect.ha", when using AT&T U-Verse?

Tags: isp, browser-cache, dsl-modem

When browsing the web, I occasionally get redirected to "/cgi-bin/redirect.ha".  Closing the browser or flushing the cache seems to fix it sometimes, but not always.  Sometimes I'll see from Google:

> Error 404. That’s an error. The requested URL /cgi-bin/redirect.ha was not found on this server. That’s all we know.

AT&T support was useless on fixing this issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a known **bug** in the **Motorola NVG510** modem supplied by **AT&T U-Verse**.  It has nothing to do with your computer or browser, and it's not a virus or abuse attack:

Basically, when the NVG510 looses connection, rather than giving you an error message it redirects all traffic to "/cgi-bin/redirect.ha".  Thus visiting to "www.example.com/whatiwant/" returns a redirect to "/cgi-bin/redirect.ha".  The browser is free to cache such data, and may do exactly that.  Thus you sort of randomly ended up with "redirect.ha" even after your modem retains connection.

Some details on fixes are at http://earlz.net/view/2013/08/03/2006/nvg510-fixer-an-android-application

Comment: I'm also seeing this with AT&T Gigapower with NVG599 modem. Except i'm seeing `/cgi-bin/ipdiags.ha`.

Comment: According to https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-get-rid-of-AT-Ts-redirect-error-page a couple of the issues are that (1) the modem/router returns a 301 redirect, which your browser caches, and (2) AT&T has some kind of nonstandard DNS setup. Apparently changing your DNS settings can help.